# Issue with INSERT operation usine Breeze.Persistence.EFCore

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, breeze

I am encountering a persistent issue with the `Breeze.Persistence.EFCore v7.0.1` library while trying to save new entities. The error message I receive is:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', table 'dbo.Clients'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Here's an overview of the situation:

- The issue occurs when saving new entities.
- I'm using a `Guid` data type for the `Id` property/column.
- The Id value is automatically generated by `breeze.js` on the client side.
- This `Id` value is successfully transmitted to the server and is present in the entity.
- The `Id` property is explicitly marked with the `[Key]` attribute.
- `UPDATE` and `DELETE` are working correctly.

I have verified the entity's state on the server, and it shows the `Id` with a valid value. This suggests that the issue might not be with the entity's `Id` assignment or transmission. I suspect there might be a configuration or compatibility issue with `Breeze.Persistence.EFCore`, especially considering the other operations work fine.

Debugged it till [`HandleAdded()`](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.server.net/blob/743d90b1a1febbc997fa8c7336eab81f8355268d/DotNet/Breeze.Persistence.EFCore/EFPersistenceManager.cs#L359) method where there is a `// HACK` comment. May it be related somehow? `IsTemporary` property is set to `true` there but the `RealValue` stays null.

[image: Entity details before save]

Has anyone faced a similar issue or have insights on what could be causing this specific INSERT operation to fail? Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

P.S. it's not the first project I develop using Breeze so I believe I made most things right (as usual) so I believe I've set up everything correctly.

## UPD

- Updated to `v7.2.1` latest stable - didn't help
- According to @steve-schmitt advise I tried to set Id manually before save but that didn't help. `BeforeEntitySave()` methods fires first and just rewrites the client's value and then `IsTemporary` is set to `true` is doesn't care of the value origin and fails the same wasy

## UPD2 (workable)

- As @gert-arnold mentioned I forgot to set `AutoGeneratedKeyType` to `None`. Fixed that on client side (`breeze.js`):

```
import * as breeze from 'breeze-client';

let manager = new breeze.EntityManager(this.serviceUrl);
manager.fetchMetadata().then(() => {
                register(this.manager.metadataStore)
            });

function extend(store: breeze.MetadataStore) {
    metadataStore.getAsEntityType("Client")
        .setProperties({ autoGeneratedKeyType: breeze.AutoGeneratedKeyType.None });
}
```

After this new entities do not have id at all and set on the server side via `BeforeEntitySave()`. Despite this is not the way I expected still it works.

Going to open an issue on GitHub and then update the post.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `AutoGeneratedKeyType` is `Identity`.  You can see that in your QuickWatch screen shot.

Identity means that the **database** will generate the keys, so Breeze should not attempt to insert anything into that column.  That's why it makes the RealValue NULL.

I don't think there is a Breeze AutoGeneratedKeyType of "Guid", but that's what would be needed here.  Instead, you'll need to use `AutoGeneratedKeyType.None` and manually generate your Guids on the client.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I though about this but doubted because in previous versions (`Breeze.ContextProvider` for .NET Framework) I never generated an Id on my own. It was so convenient that Breeze took care about everything. And still `breeze.js` on the client side generates the Id - shouldn't server side support it?

Comment: Yes, Breeze should support that!  It should have an `AutoGeneratedKeyType.Guid`, and the metadata for an entity should use that type if the entity key is a Guid.  Perhaps you can open an [issue](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.server.net/issues).